# get mongodb _id object after upsert with php

Tags: php, mongodb, upsert

is it possible to get the new/updated _id after the query?
example code:

```
$key = array( 'something' => 'unique' );
$data = array( '$inc' => array( 'someint' => 1 ) );
$mongodb->db->collection->update( $key, $data, array( 'upsert' => true ) );
```

$key is not holding the new/old _id object and i assume that $data will not either because its just an instruction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes -- It is possible using a single query.**

MongoDB includes a [`findAndModify`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command that can atomically modify a document and return it (by default it actually returns the document before it's been modified).

The PHP drivers don't include a convenient method for this on the collection class (yet -- check out [this bug](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-117)), but it can still be used (note that my PHP is terrible, so I may very well have made a syntax error in the following snippet):

```
$key = array( 'something' => 'unique' );
$data = array( '$inc' => array( 'someint' => 1 ) );
$result = $mongodb->db->command( array(
    'findAndModify' => 'collection',
    'query' => $key,
    'update' => $data,
    'new' => true,        # To get back the document after the upsert
    'upsert' => true,
    'fields' => array( '_id' => 1 )   # Only return _id field
) );
$id = $result['value']['_id'];
```

Comment: ahh - the `findAndModify` I so rarely use it I always forget it exists :) - Its good to be proven wrong occasionally ;)

Comment: @gnarf: No worries. What strikes me as odd is that there isn't a way of getting the _id automatically in PHP -- I'm used to the Python drivers which return the _id on every [upsert](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save)

Answer (score 15):

Just in case someone stumbles across this question like I did, Mongo will actually modify the input array when you call MongoCollection->save(); - appending the id to the end.
So, if you call:

```
$test = array('test'=>'testing');
mongocollection->save($test);
echo $test['_id'];
```

You will have the mongo id for that object.

Comment: Fantastic. I can see no purpose in using the overly complex `findAndModify` rather than a traditional `save` if it's a standard, no frills, `upsert`.

Comment: Aha! I was wondering why there wasn't a way to get the `_id` for an upsert in PHP... This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and worked around it by querying back the _id after the upsert. I thought I'd add some of my findings in case they're useful to anyone who comes here searching for info.

When the upsert results in a new document being created in the collection, the returned object contains the _id (here's a print_r of an example):

```
Array

(

[updatedExisting] => 0

[upserted] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 506dc50614c11c6ebdbc39bc
    )

[n] => 1
[connectionId] => 275
[fsyncFiles] => 7
[err] => 
[ok] => 1
)
```

You can get the _id from this:

```
$id = (string)$obj['upserted'];
```

However, if the upsert resulted in an existing document being updated then the returned object does not contain _id.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot :

```
function save($data, $id = null) {
    $mongo_id = new MongoId($id);
    $criteria = array('_id' => $mongo_id);
    // Wrap a '$set' around the passed data array for convenience
    $update = array('$set' => $data);
    $collection->update($criteria, $update, array('upsert' => true));
}
```

So lets say the passed `$id` is null, a fresh `MongoId` is created, otherwise it just converts the existing `$id` to a MongoId object.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

The update method returns an array with the ID of the document UPSERTED:

```
Array
(
    [ok] => 1
    [nModified] => 0
    [n] => 1
    [err] => 
    [errmsg] => 
    [upserted] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 5511da18c8318aa1701881dd
        )
    [updatedExisting] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set fsync to true in an update/upsert, to get the _id returned to the object that has been passed to the update.

```
$save = array ('test' => 'work');
$m->$collection->update(criteria, $save, array('fsync' => true, 'upsert' => true));
echo $save['_id']; //should have your _id of the obj just updated.
```