# MongoDB findAndModify, is there an implementation in PHP for that?

Tags: php, mongodb, find, semantics

I looked for findAndModify semantics in PHP but couldn't find any, would be happy to get reference / examples for this functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get mongodb _id object after upsert with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434009/get-mongodb-id-object-after-upsert-with-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-117) issue for the fact that it's missing from the PHP driver, which includes a workaround:

> It's a database command, you can do:
>
> $db->command(array("findandmodify" => "collectionName", "query" =>
>   ...));
>
> See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findandmodify+Command for
>   details.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking for this--This has now been implemented.
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php